# How to show a vector space is closed under an Operation?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, vectors

Consider an operator $A$ acting on a vector in some $n$-dimensional vector space $V = \operatorname{span}(v_1, v_2,..., v_n)$. How does one show that the vector space is closed under the operator (i.e. $Av_j \rightarrow v_i$, where $v_j$ and $v_i$ are in $\operatorname{span}(v_1, v_2, ..., v_n)$ ). Is it simply testing the resultant vector to see if it satisfies the conditions for an element in our initial vector space or is there something more? Are there some general conditions for an operator that, if satisfied, imply such closure?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $V = \operatorname{span}(v_1, v_2,..., v_n)$ and if you want to show that $A(V) \subseteq V$, then you have to show that $Av_j \in V$ for $j=1,...,n$.